# Annotating class with xml annotations along with jpa annotations

Tags: java, json, xml, hibernate

Can I annotate a pojo with jpa annotations along with xml attributes annotations so that I can pass json as payload and store it in db as xml after converting it so to avoid converting the format again and again would a class will be enough just by providing annotations.

Comment: Yes. What's your question?

Comment: I meant to ask whether one pojo can used to annotate xml representation as well as jpa entity.

Comment: Yes you can. But why do you not want to seperate concerns by creating a separate class for the xml/json model? I had the very same issue in a real project for a client. At first you might think that you will save time by overloading one class. But I would suggest to create a separate class for the json serialization.